# finding a point on a linear line

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

so I have some code that generates a planet and this planet has LODS And Culling but the culling does not dynamically change so when the planet is far away the edges are missing and when I'm close to the planet there is more of the planet showing then needed so I need to dynamically change the **cullingAngle** Variable Based on **distanceToPlayer**

[image]

so when **distanceToPlayer = 3000**  **cullingAngle needs to be = 1**

and when **distanceToPlayer = 1000**  **cullingAngle needs to be = 3**

my code currently for this is

```
if (distanceToPlayer < 1500){
    cullingAngle = 2.5f;
}
```

but I would like it to be dynamic like

```
cullingAngle = Calculation
```

but my 2 brain cells cant figure this out

Comment: Use the formula for a line (`y=mx+b`). In your case `b` is 4 and `m` is `-1/1000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just asking for the equation for that line, it's `cullingAngle = 4 - distanceToPlayer/1000`.

Comment: It can also just be a property: `private float CullingAngle=>4-distanceToPlayer/1000;`

Comment: Thanks So much! but is there any way i can have a parameter to be able to adjust the rate at which it decays so its not a linear and turns into more of a exponential or bell curve?

Comment: Sure, but that'd be a different curve/question/math equation... maybe just play around on Wolfram Alpha until you find a curve you like?